# Extracting reason for Anomaly from H2OAutoEncoderEstimator

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I'm currently training an anomaly detection model (in Python) using H2o's `H2OAutoEncoderEstimator` and I've had good results at finding anomalous records in my test dataset.

However, I'd like to take this a step further and try and pinpoint the reason for the anomaly (if possible).

I've tried making sense of the `.predict()` output for my model which looks as follows:

[image]

How do I interpret this output? I've tried the docs but found it of very little help.

Also, for those of you that have tried similar approaches, could you recommend a technique for extracting the reasons for the anomaly once detected using the tools provided in the H2o library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My first step would be to use K-LIME (K local interpretable model-agnostic explanations) to see if it can build a model to explain your autoencoder model.

K-LIME is available in [H2O's R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.10.5.2/topics/h2o.klime) and (I believe) Python.

[This is a helpful explanation](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/understanding-model-predictions-lime) of the LIME concept.

Comment: K-LIME was an experimental feature that was removed from H2O.  You won't be able to find it in recent versions, sorry!  Instead, I'd recommend using the lime package: https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Tutorial_H2O_continuous_and_cat.html